# JQuery: append item before element's HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to append some HTML before the existing HTML of an element. I have tried:

```
$("p").each(function(index){
  $(this).prepend('HELLO! ');
});
```

But this places it before `<p>`.

I've also tried:

```
$(this).html().prepend('HELLO! ');
```

The result I need to get would look like:

```
<p>HELLO! This is existing text</p>
```

Would anyone know the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`.html( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function) to update the `innerHTML` of all the `<p>` elements.

```
$('p').html(function(i, old) {
    return 'HELLO! ' + old;
});
```

```js
$('p').html(function(i, old) {
    return 'HELLO! ' + old;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>World!</p>
<p>TJ</p>
```

If all the `<p>` elements just contains normal text and not HTML, [`.text( function )`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) can also be used instead of `.html()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("p").each(function(index){
  $(this).before('HELLO! ');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>paragraph</p>

<p>paragraph</p>
```

use [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.